# How to make Map.Center change instantly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a map control with its center bound to a `GeoCoordinate` property in the viewmodel.
The map's center properly changes whenever the property changes.
By default, the map has a animation for changing its view (it gradually moves to the new location).
However, I do not want this animation.
I would like the map to instantly center on the new location.
I have already set the animation of the map: `AnimationLevel="None"`, but it didn't seem to change anything.

The animation normally looks really nice, however, this app only deals with locations in a very small view. With small changes to the map's center, the animation just makes everything look like its shaking and it takes too long to finish.

As always, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had have related problem. Try to set `AnimationLevel` to something else and than set back to `None`

Comment: That is really weird. I wonder why it is like that? Do you know if has been a bug submitted on this issue?